# Getting Info from a Magnet Uri

Tags: php, magnet-uri

I am attempting to extract information from a magnet uri. For example I want to know the filename and the size of the file from a magnet uri. I know this can be done just by looking at the url and checking the dn and xl parameters of the magnet uri.

But what if those parameters and not provided? uTorrent seems to accept those links without dn and xl parameters and eventually fills it out by itself.

Is there a way similar to extracting info from a magnet uri like a .torrent file? The way I extract info from a torrent file is by either scraping the url or opening and reading the .torrent file content. If there a way i could do something similar with a magnet file?

I am attempting to code this in php.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct uTorrent just gets the .torrent file using DHT from the swarm. Magnet links are basically a way to torrent the torrent file (if that makes sense).

You could use a [PHP torrent client](http://sourceforge.net/projects/torrentflux/) though.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to actually connect to the `xs`, `as`, `mt`, or `tr` address and ask that source about the file.

The remote end could be an HTTP fileserver or a P2P network address, so doing this right would consist of writing a rudimentary torrent client (and a crippled one, since it probably wouldn't support DHT peer-finding and caching).